# Xcode 4.3.2 compiler settings crashing xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was just asked to update my settings in xcode as I was getting warnings to do so since upgrading to Xcode 4.3.2 after I upgraded Xcode started to crash everytime I tried to compile and run the application I am working on.. no errors all of a suddon Xcode just becomes unresponsive..

How can I fix this.
the compiler settings in my Project and Target are set to default LLVM compiler 3.1

If I change these I get Dozens and Dozens of errors. Dose anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Listing some of the errors might help people solve your problem.

Comment: There are no errors..it just hangs. it says "attaching to prgram-name" then nothing...  it just stays like that.

Comment: You said you had "dozens and dozens of errors", Now you say you have none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the compiler didn't 'crash', the simulator bridge daemon 'crashed'.  What is really happening is that you are attempting to run your app, when an instance of it is caught in the simulator.  What I've found is that if you switch to an earlier simulator SDK, build and run, then stop the build and restart the simulator, it works just fine again.

If you do however get the error 'failed to register com.mycompany.myapp with the bootstrap server', then restarting your Mac is the only way to fix it.

Comment: ahh.. How do you change the simulator version. It is only showing 5.1 in the section where you press run up the top right.

Comment: Press Cmd+, and download the other sims.

Comment: AHH found it, XCode > Prefrences > Downloads shows you all of the simulators you can download and test on :)

Comment: lol wow.. answered me as I was answering myself :P